# r download url file with partial name

Tags: r, file, download

I am programming in R.  I need to download a set of files from an http: address.  The naming format of the file refers to a date/time period but also contains additional numbering that is not recognizable.  For example for the file below the first set of numbers refers to the date 2014/10/24 at 05:10am but the second batch of numbers is not recognizable.  All files on the webpage follow this standard format.

http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/MCCDispatch/PUBLIC_MCCDISPATCH_201410240510_0000000258279329.zip

My question is:  How do I download the file with only partial name information?

For example if I wanted to download the file relating to the 6:30 time period I know that the url prefix is as below, but would not know the numbers that follow after: http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/MCCDispatch/PUBLIC_MCCDISPATCH_201410240630_??????????????.zip

Comment: You're not going to be able to tell the site; give me some file. Instead, you'll need to fetch the directory list ( http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/MCCDispatch/ ) and search it for the correct file - and have code to handle what to do if there is more than one such file, etc. - Please try to do this, and then ask a specific question relating to your code, instead of "How can I do X".

Comment: This isn't really an R specific thing. The web just wasn't defined to support partial file matching for security reasons. That's something that would have to be set up at the server. Or the server would have to give you a listing of available files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually in luck. Because you have a directory listing. Essentially, you have to download the list of links and then grep them. Here's how you would go about doing that.

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/CURRENT/MCCDispatch/"
parsed <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(parsed, "//@href")
```

Now you have a list of URLs that you can search through and choose the one that's appropriate.

Hint: `grep("pattern",links)`

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  Sorry, should have mentioned it was in a directory structure.